# Adding the values of each chr(ord() character in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, chr, ord

```
codeword = input('Enter codeword : ')
codeword = codeword.lower().replace(" ", "")
for i in codeword:
    old = (Chr(ord(i)))

encrypt = input('Enter text to encrypt : ')
encrypt = encrypt.lower().replace(" ", "")
for i in encrypt:
    new = (Chr(ord(i)))

value = new + old
for i in value:
    print(Chr(ord(i)))
```

I am doing encryption and decryption for my GCSE computing, I already made a program that successfully encryptions text to the value of 5 letters in the alphabet ('a' would become 'f') the alphabet and then a program that decrypts it. However, I also have to write a program that adds the values of a codeword to the text
 and prints the new letter. So, for example, if the codeword was 'gcses' and the text 'hello' it would print o (7 + 8) h (3 + 5) e (19 + 12) q (5 + 12) h (19 + 15)

The code I have at the moment I believe is vaguely on the right track, however, I would like to know if it is possible to add the values of two ord() functions to carry out this program. Thanks. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can add two `ord()` functions, but you would be fairly complicated, because `ord('a')` is not 0, and therefore you couldn't use `% 26` without subtracting `ord('a')` first.  Example: `(ord('b') + ord('f') - ord('a')) % 26 + ord('a')` is about what one letter would need to go through.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise it would be so complicated! Are you aware of any other method that could potentially produce the same results? Many thanks.

Comment: You can use `string.lowercase` and `string.uppercase`.  For example, `string.lowercase[string.lowercase.index('b) + string.lowercase.index('f') % 26]` would get the same results as the example I gave above.  You would need to check to see if your two letters are in `string.lowercase` or `string.uppercase`, but that's about how I have done it.  You could also use `string.letters` which has lowercase *and* uppercase letters right in a row.  For that, if `string.letters.index(letter)` is >= 26, it is uppercase.  Otherwise, it is lowercase.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this might be to add a lookup string containing the alphabet in order to find the letter numbers...

```
alphabet = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
print alphabet.find('b')
# prints '2'
print alphabet[alphabet.find('g') + alphabet.find('h')]
# prints 'o' as expected.
```

You would need to handle overflow though (%26 would work)